# How to fix the type-errors and attribute-errors that are associated with the hashmap?

Tags: python, algorithm

```py
import csv
from hashmap import HashMap
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2


# initialize variables to store data
location_map = HashMap()
item_map = HashMap()
order_map = HashMap()


def load_location_data():
    with open('location_data.csv', 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            location_name = row[0]
            inventory = row[1:]
            location_map[location_name] = inventory


def load_order_data():
    with open('order_data.csv', 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            order_id = row[0]
            locations = row[1:]
            order_map[order_id] = locations


def load_serialised_data():
    with open('serialised_data.csv', 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            location_name = row[0]
            item = row[1]
            quantity = int(row[2])
            if location_name not in item_map:
                item_map[location_name] = {}
            item_map[location_name][item] = quantity


def find_location_inventory():
    location_name = input("Enter location name: ")
    inventory = location_map[location_name]
    print(f"Location inventory for {location_name}:")
    for item in inventory:
        print(item)


def find_distance():
    start_location = input("Enter starting location: ")
    end_location = input("Enter ending location: ")
    start_coords = tuple(float(x) for x in location_map[start_location][:2])
    end_coords = tuple(float(x) for x in location_map[end_location][:2])
    # calculate distance using Haversine formula
    earth_radius = 6371.01  # km
    lat1, lon1 = start_coords
    lat2, lon2 = end_coords
    delta_lat = lat2 - lat1
    delta_lon = lon2 - lon1
    a = (sin(delta_lat / 2)) ** 2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * (sin(delta_lon / 2)) ** 2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
    distance = earth_radius * c
    print(f"Distance from {start_location} to {end_location}: {distance:.2f} km")


def find_order_route():
    order_id = input("Enter order ID: ")
    locations = order_map[order_id]
    print(f"Route for order {order_id}:")
    total_distance = 0
    for i in range(len(locations) - 1):
        start_location = locations[i]
        end_location = locations[i + 1]
        start_coords = tuple(float(x) for x in location_map[start_location][:2])
        end_coords = tuple(float(x) for x in location_map[end_location][:2])
        # calculate distance using Haversine formula
        earth_radius = 6371.01  # km
        lat1, lon1 = start_coords
        lat2, lon2 = end_coords
        delta_lat = lat2 - lat1
        delta_lon = lon2 - lon1
        a = (sin(delta_lat / 2)) ** 2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * (sin(delta_lon / 2)) ** 2
        c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
        distance = earth_radius * c
        total_distance += distance
        print(f"From {start_location} to {end_location}: {distance:.2f} km")
    print(f"Total distance for order {order_id}: {total_distance:.2f} km")

def location_overview():
    print("Location overview:")
    for location, items in location_map.items():
        print(f"{location}: {len(items)} items in inventory")

def inventory_overview(inventory):
    total_items = 0
    total_value = 0

    for item, info in inventory.items():
        total_items += info['quantity']
        total_value += info['price'] * info['quantity']
        print(f"{item.capitalize()}: {info['quantity']} units, ${info['price']} each")

    print(f"\nTotal number of items: {total_items}")
    print(f"Total value of inventory: ${total_value}")

def save_data():
    with open('serialised_data.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        for loc, items in item_map.items():
            for item, quantity in items.items():
                writer.writerow([loc, item, quantity])
        print("Data saved successfully")

# menu loop
while True:
    print("Welcome to the Interactive Menu:")
    print("1. Load data")
    print("2. Find and display location Inventory")
    print("3. Find and dislpay distance between two locations")
    print("4. Find and display route for collecting order")
    print("5. Location Overview")
    print("6. Inventory Overview")
    print("7. Save data")
    print("8. Exit")

    choice = input("Select which option you would like to choose: ")

    if choice == "1":
        load_location_data()
        load_order_data()
        load_serialised_data()
        print("Data successfully loaded")

    elif choice == "2":
        find_location_inventory()

    elif choice == "3":
        find_distance()

    elif choice == "4":
        find_order_route()

    elif choice == "5":
        location_overview()

    elif choice == "6":
        inventory_overview()

    elif choice == "7":
        save_data()
        print("Data saved successfully")

    elif choice == "8":
        #code for option8
        print("Exiting the interactive menu")
        break

    else:
        print("Invalid option was selected")



class Node:
    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def search(self, key):
        curr = self.head
        while curr != None:
            if curr.key == key:
                return curr
            curr = curr.next
        return None

    def insert(self, key, value):
        node = Node(key, value)
        node.next = self.head
        self.head = node

    def delete(self, key):
        prev = None
        curr = self.head
        while curr != None:
            if curr.key == key:
                if prev == None:
                    self.head = curr.next
                else:
                    prev.next = curr.next
                return True
            prev = curr
            curr = curr.next
        return False

class HashMap:
    def __init__(self, capacity=16):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.size = 0
        self.table = [LinkedList() for _ in range(capacity)]

    def _hash(self, key):
        return hash(key) % self.capacity

    def get(self, key):
        index = self._hash(key)
        node = self.table[index].search(key)
        if node:
            return node.value
        return None

    def put(self, key, value):
        index = self._hash(key)
        node = self.table[index].search(key)
        if node:
            node.value = value
        else:
            self.table[index].insert(key, value)
            self.size += 1
            if self.size > self.capacity * 0.75:
                self._resize()

    def delete(self, key):
        index = self._hash(key)
        if self.table[index].delete(key):
            self.size -= 1

    def _resize(self):
        self.capacity *= 2
        new_table = [LinkedList() for _ in range(self.capacity)]
        for bucket in self.table:
            curr = bucket.head
            while curr != None:
                index = self._hash(curr.key)
                new_table[index].insert(curr.key, curr.value)
                curr = curr.next
        self.table = new_table
```

The HashMap function wasn't originally written using linked lists, but the same errors were still present. I rewrote the code using a linked list to factor in the collisions that would be caused, but the same errors persisted. The main goal of the code is to make the interactive menu work by displaying the information that gets imported by the CSV files. Whenever I run the interactive menu and choose an option to run, I either get an attribute error or a typeerror that is associated with the HashMap file. I have tried rewriting the code in different forms but the same problem keeps coming back.

The following is what is in the CSV files.

location_data:

```
"Location name", "products", "distance"
"Location A", "Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 4", "40.7128, -74.2312"
"Location B", "Item 1, Item 2", "35.2321, -83.2415"
"Location C", "Item 1, Item 2, Item 3", "41.1633, -52.2352"
"Location D", "Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 4, Item 5", "32.2512, -85.3425"
```

order_data:

```
"Order ID", "Order route"
"Order 1", "Location A, Location B"
"Order 2", "Location A"
"Order 3", "Location B, Location C"
"Order 4", "Location C, Location A, Location D"
```

serialised_data:

```
"Location", "Items", "Quantity"
"Location A", "Item 1", "4"
"Location A", "Item 2", "5"
"Location B", "Item 5", "2"
"Location C", "Item 2", "7"
"Location D", "Items 4", "9"
"Location D", "Item 3", "10"
```

Comment: Do you mean you have a `TypeError: 'HashMap' object does not support item assigment`? If so, it also indicates where the error comes from: `location_map[location_name] = inventory`.

Comment: Could you also explain why `HashMap.table` is a list of `LinkedList`s? What is the point of having `LinkedList`s objects if you do not use them as such?

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

The specific problem you have is that the line `location_map[location_name] = inventory` raises the following error: `TypeError: 'HashMap' object does not support item assigment`. This is also not the only line that will raise this error, but every line that has `hashmap[index] = item` (with `hashmap` a `HashMap` instance, `index` an index, or key, and `item` an item to assign to the index/key `index`).
This is due to the operation you are trying to do (item assignment) not being implemented in your `HashMap` class. If you go through this class though, you will find that there are other methods implemented that might help you, namely the `get` and `put` methods.

Here `location_map[location_name] = inventory` would then translate to `location_map.put(location_name, inventory)`. This is true for anywhere you need to associate a value to a key.
On the other hand, `item_map[location_name][item] = quantity` will translate to `item_map.get(location_name)[item]`. This is true for anywhere you need to retrieve a value from its associated key.

Once this is fixed, you should be able to load data, as I've been able to.
This is not the end of the errors though. And this is why I asked in comments why you were using multiple `HashMap`s, each of which contain multiple `LinkedList`s. I have not found any use for a linked list in your script. I may have overlooked something, but without more details, there is nothing I see that would justify it, as it will unnecessarily complexify the code.

In any case, with or without linked lists, you will need to implement/work around the absence of the `items` method, which is specific to `dict` objects. For this you will need to think about what the result of this method should be, and then about how to do this. (This is the part where I stumbled upon your use of linked lists, which add a layer of complexity).

Hope this helps.